# Angular Django Image Transfer

Tags: angularjs, django, upload, media

I am developing a Web Application using Angular.js and Django. I am successfully uploading images using JSON which get stored in Django using the Base64ImageField serializer. Here is my settings.py media configuration:
`MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')`
`MEDIA_URL = '/media/'`

After uploading I can see my images in the /media folder. I also added the following line to my urls.py:
`urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`

However I am not able to display the images on the frontend, though my path is correct:
`<img ng-src="{{vm.images[0].image}}"></img>`
`<img ng-src="http://localhost:8000{{vm.images[0].image}}"></img>`

My angular image object is just a path to the image, the received JSON looks something like this:
 `{image: "/media/images/34f5.jpg"}`

Comment: Does the uploading occurs at the same page as the <img> tag? If yes you might need to reload the image

Comment: Yes, but the image also won't show after reloading. http://i65.tinypic.com/2m636za.png